# Beginner Java Controlled Loop Not Producing Expected Results

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, counter

I am trying to create a diamond shape (made of asterisks), however I just cant seem to get the bottom right leg not right? Why is my code incorrect? Thanks in advance

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Diamond 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the size of the diamond and press enter:");    
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = kb.nextInt();

        for (int c0 = 1; c0 <= N; c0++)     // establishes the number of lines in the diamond                
        {

            for (int c1 = 0; c1 <= N-1-c0; c1++) System.out.print(" "); // establishes the number of spaces before each asterisk
            System.out.print("*");

            for (int c2 = 3; c2 <= c0*2; c2++) System.out.print(" "); //adds a space between both asterisks. This boolean check repeats for each line
            System.out.print("*");
            System.out.println();

        }

        for (int c0 = 1; c0 <= N; c0++)   // establishes the number of lines in the diamond                
        {

            for (int c1 = N; c1 >= N+2-c0; c1--) System.out.print(" "); // establishes the number of spaces before each asterisk
            System.out.print("*");

            for (int c2 = N*2; c2 >= c0+2; c2--) System.out.print(" "); //adds a space between both asterisks. This boolean check repeats for each line
            System.out.print("*");
            System.out.println();

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things are a lot more readable if you extract a method. But first,

```
for (int c2 = N*2; c2 >= c0+2; c2--) System.out.print(" ");
```

should be something like

```
for (int c2 = 0; c2 < (N-c0)*2; c2++) System.out.print(" ");
```

**or** something like

```
static String getSpaces(int n) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sb.append(' ');
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

which you could then call like

```
for (int c0 = 0; c0 < N; c0++) {
    System.out.print(getSpaces(N - c0));
    System.out.print("*");
    System.out.print(getSpaces(c0 * 2));
    System.out.print("*");
    System.out.println();
}
for (int c0 = 1; c0 <= N; c0++) {
    System.out.print(getSpaces(c0));
    System.out.print("*");
    System.out.print(getSpaces((N - c0) * 2));
    System.out.print("*");
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: this did the trick. I haven't learned those other objects yet, however your fix to my existing code did the trick

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked your program a little bit... you need to do some more work to get rid of some extra asterisk . At least it will give you some more idea:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Diamond 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the size of the diamond and press enter:");    
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = kb.nextInt();

        for (int c0 = 1; c0 <= N; c0++)     // establishes the number of lines in the diamond                
        {

            for (int c1 = 0; c1 <= N-1-c0; c1++) System.out.print(" "); // establishes the number of spaces before each asterisk
            System.out.print("*");

            for (int c2 = 3; c2 <= c0*2; c2++) System.out.print(" "); //adds a space between both asterisks. This boolean check repeats for each line
            System.out.print("*");
            System.out.println();

        }


        for (int i = N ; i >= 1; i--)
        {
              for (int j = 0; j < (N - i); j++)
                    System.out.print(" ");
              for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
                    System.out.print("*");
             for (int k = 1; k < i; k++)
                    System.out.print("*");
              System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```